# AngularJS - Why my request is not sending the json object to the server?

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

I am using $http for sending post request with json object to the nodeJS server but when I print the request params on the server side then it shows empty.Here is the code.

```
$http.post('/login',userObj);
```

This is how I handled request on server

```
server.post(/login/,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: Well, you're sending a request body, as JSON. Not as form-encoded parameters.

Comment: Shouldn't `(userObj)` be `userObj`>

Comment: @Igor it shows `{ }` on the server side.

Comment: I see this as two questions? 1) Is the request sending the data? 2) Does the server have a route that receives the data. For 1, check the network tab. For 2, there are a variety of possible points where things have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your AngularJS code. You need to use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) in Nodejs to handle the request.

Comment: @pritesh you can use `app.use(bodyParser.json())` like in the documentation of body-parser.

Comment: @pritesh what exactly is not working? Have you tried something similar to documentation page like this: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#express-route-specific ?